# How are sensitive information such a database password and SMTP login stored?

Tags: c#, winforms, security, app-config, password-protection

I have a desktop application where I need to connect to a MySQL database and send some emails using the SMTP protocol and to perform this, I need the database password and SMTP login somewhere and the application be able to read it at runtime. But how does the real world's .NET applications protect that information? What kind of protection do they use? I was considering to encrypt my own settings file, such as an encrypted XML file which gets decrypted at runtime. But even so, I must have the key to decrypt it somwehere in the source cod.

Comment: I don't does this any help for you https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is you can't. Every string you write in your appconfig file or constant in your code should be considered like a public information. This is particularly true for .Net application.

For database, the best ways to go is using Integrated Security to delegate this task to Windows, using a public user who have only the right your application need, or using a Web Service (maybe with WCF) to prevent direct exposition of your database.

You could also let each users configure theses connection string on the first startup, then encrypt and store them in his settings with something like [Windows Data Protection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995355.aspx) and the [ProtectedData Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata(v=vs.110).aspx) or rely on traditional network protection strategy.